# How to leave a tile empty

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tiles

Is it possible to leave a tile empty? Let's say I have three tiles in a page: header, body, footer. Can i simply add a body and a footer and leave header empty?

```
<body class="claro">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container" class="container">
    <div id="hd">
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
    </div>
    <div id="bd">
    <hr/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    </div>
    <div id="ft">
    <hr/>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I want to use this once like this :

```
   <definition name="base" template="...">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/base/header.jspx" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/base/body.jspx" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/base/footer.jspx" />
</definition>
```

And once like this :

```
 <definition name="base" template="...">
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/base/body.jspx" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/base/footer.jspx" />
</definition>
```

Currently the second usage blows up. Saying i haven't defined header.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the ignore attribute:

```
<tiles:insertAttribute name="header" ignore="true"/>
```

According to the [docs](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/tiles/insertAttribute.html):

> If this attribute is set to true, and the attribute specified by the name does not exist, simply return without writing anything. The default value is false, which will cause a runtime exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

You could just provide an empty header page in a base definition and then replace body and footer in the more specific ones.

You could also just set the value to an empty string:

```
<put-attribute name="header" value=""/>
```